# jQuery serialize remove empty Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big form, that will be serialized by a jQuery function.

The problem is that I need to remove from this form before being serialized all the empty values.

I found a way to successfully remove all the empty input text fields, but not the selections.

It does not work properly with select dropdowns.

Ceck below:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submForm').validate({ 
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // Do cleanup first
            $('input:text[value=\"\"]', '#submForm').remove();
            $('select option:empty', '#submForm').remove();
            var serialized = $('#submForm').serialize();
             $.get('".$moduleURL."classes/DO_submission.php', serialized);
            window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 8000);
            return false;
            form.submit(); 
        }
    })
});
```

It should completely remove the dropdown selections where the values are empty. Not only the options but the entire select box should not be included in the serialize function.

How do I achieve this?

```
$('select option:empty', '#submForm').remove();
```

This code is not working as it should..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with 'empty select' you mean that the user has not chosen a 'valid' option (for example the fist option of a select is `<option value=''>Select your value</option>` )why don't you iterate on the select and check their value?

```
$('select').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === ''){//this assumes that your empty value is ''
       $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

EDIT - sorry for the error, i missed the last parenthesis, i tried it and it works for me

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to achieve. Grazie Nicola. Ci provo. Ti prego non scappare!! NE ho davvero bisogno!!

Comment: @Diego There's a missing `);` at the very end.

Answer (score 2):

First, a `select` can not have an empty value. It will default to the first `option` if the `selected` attribute is not set.

Second, `$('select option:empty')` selects the empty `option`s. To do something, an `option` should have a value, so afaik the selector will never work.

What you need to do is check all `select`s to see if they have a different value than their default, and if it is not the case, remove them.

Comment: @Diego See [Nicola](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254059/jquery-serialize-remove-empty-select/6254140#6254140)'s answer. It's a good start, but it will not work for other default values.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('select option:selected:empty').parent().remove();
```

Edited after reading Nicola's comment.

Comment: `$('select option:empty').parent().remove();`  removes all select with an empty value even if it is not selected, the other doesn't work i don't think you cane use selctors in that way: it works with other properties

Answer (score 0):

I would just instead of serlizing  the the whole form I would use [jquery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and then all you have to do is call

```
 $('#submForm').ajaxSubmit({/.../});
```